# EO HtmlToPdf StartPosition multiple columns

Tags: c#, html-to-pdf

I am using Essential Objects HtmlToPdf and doing a first page header that is larger.  Using one column and specifying a positive StartPosition everything works fine.  However, when I split on to two columns the first column is shifted down but the second one is not.

Is there a way to have the second column be shifted down by the same amount?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for anyone who comes across this in the future.

```
HtmlToPdf.Options.StartColumnIndex = -1;
```

will make the second column follow the StartPosition.